# Graph shortest path confusion

Tags: graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I want to calculate the shortest path from A to F in this graph [image]

Following Dijkstra's algorithm I reach E and then go to C, but then I can't comeback to E, how do I solve this?

My steps were:

- All cost to infinity but a, that I've set to 0.
- From A I've updated b and c, considering b had a 26 cost, I went to b.
- Then d, e and finally c

Comment: With Dijkstra's algorithm, you remember every place you've been.  So once you discover you've been to E and C, the next easiest to get to is....  But shouldn't you get to C before E?

Comment: @Teepeemm I went to B first because it had less cost than going to C in the first place and then I followed the path from there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you’re taking the shortest path from wherever you find yourself currently, and not calculating the total distance to get to a node.  Let’s step through it in detail.

Dijkstra’s algorithm sets up two sets of nodes: visited (with known distances) and unvisited (with tentative distances).  We start with:

```
visited: { }
unvisited: { a(dist 0), b(dist ∞), c(dist ∞), d(dist ∞), e(dist ∞), f(dist ∞) }
```

The smallest tentative distance becomes permanent, and that node is the “current” node.  Using the current node, we update the tentative distances that the current node can reach in a shorter distance and mark the current node as visited:

```
visited: { a(0) }
unvisited: { b(26), c(50), d(∞), e(∞), f(∞) }
```

We repeat the above paragraph, making the shortest tentative distance permanent, and updating tentative distances that the current node can reach in a shorter distance and mark the current node as visited:

```
visited: { a(0), b(26) }
unvisited: { c(50), d(91), e(∞), f(∞) }
```

And again:

```
visited: { a(0), b(26), c(50) }
unvisited: { d(91), e(76), f(∞) }
```

This time, we pick e as the current node, because its tentative distance is less than d’s.  But d’s tentative distance doesn’t get updated, because we’ve already found a better distance.  Mark e visited:

```
visited: { a(0), b(26), c(50), e(76) }
unvisited: { d(91), f(101) }
```

Now d is current, but it doesn’t update any distances (we don’t need to look at visited nodes, we’ve already found the best distances there).  So we just mark it visited:

```
visited: { a(0), b(26), c(50), e(76), d(91) }
unvisited: { f(101) }
```

Now f is current, which means we’re done.

Comment: thanks for the long and detailed explanantion! The only thing that still bugs me, is how we go from node b to node c, while there's no connection between them...

Comment: We don't go from b to c.  We're looking at all possible distances to c.  Specifically, when a is current, we use that to update the tentative distance to c (so we go from a to c).  Nothing else changes that tentative distance, so by the time c is current, that distance becomes permanent.

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense! And where do you store the shortest path? the sequence of nodes that give you the shortest path between one node and another?

Comment: Whenever you write down/update a distance, you can write down the path that gives you that distance.

Comment: ok then, thanks for the patience and for the incredibly good info! Cheers